# Don't know why I'm getting blank strings C++

Tags: c++, string

When I output the following code it displays blank strings, for the name and address of my objects, to the console. I am wondering why that is, and the reason I am posting 99% of the code is because there are a few places I think the error could be. Everything is so integrated with everything else I don't want to miss something. I've tried everything I know, but I'm pretty new to C++ so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// Declare the necessary include(s)
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Account.h"

void displayAccounts(const vector<Account>);

int main()
    {
        // Declare local variables
        int i = 0;
        int size = 3;

        // Create a vector of Account objects.
        vector <Account> awesomeVector;

        // Create three person objects.
        Person orc("Lurtz", "Sarumon's Tower");
        Person nazgul("Witch King of Angmar", "Palace of Angmar");
        Person dragon("Smaug", "746 Misty Mountain Way");

        // Create three Account objects, where each account object contains a Person object.
        Account lurtz(orc, 1, 500);
        Account witchKing(nazgul, 2, 1000);
        Account smaug(dragon, 3, 1200);

        // Push these Account objects into the vector.
        awesomeVector.push_back(lurtz);
        awesomeVector.push_back(witchKing);
        awesomeVector.push_back(smaug);

        // Pass the vector to the displayAccounts function
        displayAccounts(awesomeVector);

        // Use endl to make the console more readable
        cout << endl << endl;

        // Keep the console window open with PAUSE
        system("PAUSE");

        // Return a 0
        return 0;

    }// End main

// Implementation of displayAccounts function
void displayAccounts(vector<Account> aVector)
{
    // Declare local variables
    int i = 0;
    int size = 3;

    // Display intro information
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Bank of Darkness" << endl <<endl;
    cout << "Account\t\tAccount" << endl;
    cout << "Number\t\tName\t\tAddress\t\tBalance" <<endl <<endl;

    // Create a for loop to display the information stored in each Account object
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        // Display account info
        cout << aVector[i].getAccountNum(); cout << "\t\t";
        cout << aVector[i].getPerson().getName(); cout << "\t\t";
        cout << aVector[i].getPerson().getAddress(); cout << "\t\t$";
        cout.precision(2);
        cout <<fixed << aVector[i].getAccountBalance() << endl << endl;
    }

}// End the displayAccounts function
```

---

```
// Declare necessary include(s)
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Declare the person class
class Person
{

// Declare private data
private:
    string name;
    string address;

// Declare public data
public:

    Person();

    Person(const string, const string);

    string getName();

    string getAddress();

};// End Person class
```

---

```
// Include the header file for the Person class
#include "Person.h"

Person::Person()
{
}

Person::Person(const string n, const string a)
{
    name = n;
    address = a;
}

string Person::getName()
{
    return name;
}

string Person::getAddress()
{
    return address;
}
```

---

```
// Include pragma once
#pragma once
#include "Person.h"

// Declare the Account class
class Account
{

// Declare private data
private:
    Person aPerson;
    int accountNum;
    double accountBalance;

// Declare public data
public:

    Account();

    Account(const Person, int, double);

    Person getPerson();

    int getAccountNum();

    double getAccountBalance();

};// End Account class
```

---

```
// Include the Account header file
#include "Account.h"

Account::Account()
{
}

Account::Account(const Person p, int accNum, double accBal)
{
    aPerson = p;
    accountNum = accNum;
    accountBalance = accBal;
}

Person Account::getPerson()
{
    return Person();
}

int Account::getAccountNum()
{
    return accountNum;
}

double Account::getAccountBalance()
{
    return accountBalance;
}
```

Comment: Observe that `Account::aPerson` member is initialized in the constructor, but then never used. In particular, it's not returned by `Account::getPerson`

Comment: Why do you assume the vector is size 3 instead of asking it for its size?

Comment: A class doesn't need to have a default constructor. If it makes no sense to have a Person with no name or address, consider removing the default constructor.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you! When I set it to return aPerson though I get a different error...

Comment: You are returning a copy of the Person. This may or may not be what you want.

Comment: @NeilKirk Thanks, I will remove the default constructor and ask for vector size.

Comment: `I get a different error` Are we supposed to exercise our mind-reading abilities at this point? Is it too much to ask to cite the error message, and the line it refers to?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Error: call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or conversion functions to pointer-to-pointer function type

Comment: Are you attempting `return aPerson();`, by any chance?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm attempting.

Comment: Well, what do you believe applying a function call operator to `aPerson` (which is not a function) is supposed to achieve?

Comment: I thought it would achieve what I want, I told you I am new to C++.

Comment: Well, you know enough C++ to write `return accountNum;` as opposed to `return accountNum();`, and `return accountBalance;` as opposed to `return accountBalance();`. What, in your opinion, makes returning `aPerson` different?

Comment: They aren't different in that sense, I'm tired and I made a mistake. Please inform me of what I am supposed to return to get the proper result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Accout::getPerson()` is returning a brand new `Person` object, that's why. Return `aPerson` instead.